# Is there a way to delegate bureaucratic tasks or social interactions?

Tags: negotiation

I'm freelance and have Asperger's (so I don’t have the ability to deal with a lot of social problems, keeping calm) and I wonder if there is a way to delegate some tasks so another person can do it in my representation. For example:

- I'm renting a flat: talk with tenants.
- Non-technical talks with clients (they want to renegotiate money, they do not pay, they want to do something out of contract, etc.)
- Bureaucratic tasks: I need to pay some taxes, go to the town hall
- Claim a client or public administration...

I know some of the tasks I said have a solution (lawyer to claim something for example), but I want it easier, like I think very rich people have: only one person (or business) to deal with everything.

Do you know something?

Comment: I'm not *entirely* certain this is on topic. It seems you are asking about possibly hiring a **personal assistant**. You, obviously, *can* do that. But I don't know what that has to do with freelancing.

Comment: Well, I expose the tasks I had on mind, and "rent a house" may be personal, or not if your bussiness is about rent houses, but all other tasks are tasks that I need to do because I'm freelance. This is the burocratic part of beeing LEGAL freelance. So for me it is all about freelancing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flat: assign a realstate company to rent it for you. They will take a considerable chunk of the rent, but 100% of the problems.

Taxes: I'm sure there are sass that will handle invoicing and taxing for you. I just can't give you any good references because I don't know your country.

Acquiring clients, daily talks: you can hire a marketing company/freelancer to set up ads for you, you should also learn how to advertise your work as if it were a company. A good SEO setup and referral payments (finder's fee) will drastically reduce your convincing time with clients, then having a freelance project manager will also help you get rid of the interaction with clients. Just add all of those costs to the final project.

To sum it up: the work and inconvenience are never eliminated, it's always moved elsewhere and at a cost. It's very good to get rid of boring work and delegating, it just isn't accessible to everyone. I was able to delegate most of my mundane tasks to my maid, accounting firm, etc. As you pay to have your time freed, you get more productive and engaged in your work, and very soon the cost of delegating will become small.

Always be looking for sass!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Freelancing.SE!

Unfortunately, if you need someone to handle these tasks, you'll need to hire someone or an organization to handle it for you. If you are hiring someone for all these responsibilities, you would NEED to hire the best person for the job - it could make or break you.

Comment: Any ideas on where to start looking? I said some webs about assistants but there are easy tasks mainly, like any other call center

Comment: @danirebollo I'm sorry, I don't understand your question?

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this subject since I wrote this question and, for now, the way I handle this things is creating automated tools by myself (from scratch or using customizable tools).

The tool's stack I'm using right now are:

```
-Google calendar: daily events
-Google keep: daily notes
-ESPOCRM: freelance client/customer management
-Private wiki using wikimedia: personal and freelance data
-Redmine: project management
-Dolibarr (with custom php modules): accountant tasks
-private NAS / Google drive: files storage
```